# How to create access query that'll combine two rows of data?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have no idea as how to combine two rows of data into one row? The below is how it's in a table:

```
GrantNumber     Category        FedBudget   MatchBudget  
19110     3. Purchase Services  $393,861.00   $0.00  
19110b    3. Purchase Services  $106,135.00   $0.00
```

I'd like to have the below as the result:

```
GrantNumber     Category        FedBudget   MatchBudget  
19110     3. Purchase Services  $499,996.00   $0.00
```

Comment: What is the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming GrantNumber always begins with 5 digits and need to group on that prefix, extract those digits as a group identifier. Use Val() or Left() function.

```
SELECT Val(GrantNumber) AS GN, Category, Sum(FedBudget) AS SumFB, Sum(MatchBudget) AS SumMB
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Val(GrantNumber), Category;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about one row per category?

```
select min(grantnumber), category, sum(fedbudget), sum(matchbudget)
from t
group by category;
```

It is not clear if `grantnumber` should be used to define a row -- and if so, what the rules are for combining them together.